# Alexa is slower with speech than typed commands. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, alexa-skills-kit

If commands are typed in alexa.developer.com inside the test tab, the response is fast. However if the same commands are spoken, it takes Alexa a considerable amount of time to perform the intent (20+ seconds). Skill is written in C#.

Does anybody have any idea what could be the problem?

We were handed a project from another company, so not everything is clear yet.

Comment: Alexa searches and tasks take text and returns results. If voice is provided, it must be converted to text; that takes a little bit of time.

Comment: I guess my question is then why does it take so much time to convert it to text? I checked the invocation commands and they don't seem to be extremely complex.

Comment: In normal operation speech recognition is done on remote servers. Is that the case here?

Comment: What exactly are you asking about, Peter? Do you mean Lambda?

(I apologise if my question sound stupid, I am an absolute beginner at Alexa)

Comment: The process, as I understand it, is that the voice is recorded locally, forwarded off to Amazon servers and queued for interpretation.  Then the results are forward to another service (where the "skill" resides), and the result marshaled back.  That's a lot of work.  But, 20+ sec seems like a long time (compared to friends showing off their Echoes to me).  Do you have any network infrastructure between your "test lab" and the internet that might be getting in the way

Comment: I don't think that network infrastructure is the problem.

I also tried speaking the commands at developer.amazon.com in test and it likewise took a long time.

On top of that, we have a mobile app that utilises the same API as Alexa for booking a trip and that one is instantaneous.

It really has something to do with voice recognition or the way it is processed. (I don't know what could be wrong though)

Comment: I also have noticed the same issue. After the spoken command Alexa is silent for 3-4 seconds. I couldn't find anything related to this [only this thread](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/406) something about progressive reponses where alexa indicates is working on the command. But I haven't tried it yet since it seems it only works on actual devices

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the original project had too many slots of type AMAZON.SearchQuery. From https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery

> Make sure that your skill uses no more than one AMAZON.SearchQuery slot per intent. The Amazon.SearchQuery slot type cannot be combined with another intent slot in sample utterances.

Performance has improved dramatically, after I created custom lists for those slots. For example, in our app we have a list of purposes of a trip, so I created a list called "Purposes" and inserted values such as Medical, Education, etc. Before it was listening for whatever user might say and then parsing it based on code; trying to find the needed word. Now it only registers the listed values.